# How can I turn a profit with Missions?

Tags: eve-online

I built an alt that's geared towards combat (my main is a miner), but I'm having trouble turning a profit running missions.

I can do level 2 for the Caldari Navy, but they payout isn't so huge, and repair costs tend to drive my bills to the point where I actually lose money with each mission I run, not gain it.

I carry my own armor rep, and that helps with the repair costs, these missions (plus the bounties) don't pay enough right now to warrant doing.

Any advice on how I can turn a profit so I don't have to get rid of this build?

Comment: If you're going to be running missions, you should fit so you can tank any common threat. I haven't played EVE in a while, but when I did, missions were all profit. I never spent money on repair.

Comment: Could you provide a link to your build? Maybe we can help you increase it's efficacity...

Comment: The best fits for missioning, imho, are drone-boats and laser-boats, because you won't need munitions (as long as you use T1 lens), thus decreasing your costs. (I would still advice the drone-boats user to fit a web and 1-2 small blasters, for those fast-spinning-orbiting frigates...)

And as long as you keep doing lvl 2 missions, even with a good build, you won't make that much profit... It will probably be more interesting to rush reputation grinding for your current faction, then run lvl 3 missions (guessing you don't have the skills on your combat alt for lvl 4 missions).

Comment: I noticed in your last question that you mentioned using a Caracal for missions.  Are you still using this ship?  If so, then you should be shield tanking and warping out if the enemy gets through your shields.  If you could post your fit to something like pastebin, we might be able to help you refine your fit a little bit.

Comment: If you have an armor repper, what are your repair costs?

Comment: @Schwern repair doesn't cost me anything with the repper, I just sit outside station and let it run. Provided that I haven't taken any hull damage, I don't need to pay for repairs at all, since docking up automatically fixes shields.

Comment: You mention repair costs driving up your bills to where you lose money on each mission, but you've figured out the armor repper trick.  I'm trying to figure out where you're losing money to help come up with an answer for you.  Ammo?  Hull damage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Low-level missions are not very lucrative, but you still shouldn't make a loss on them if you are doing them properly. Level 3 missions should earn you okay money, but to make a reasonable amount of money for your time you need to fly level 4 missions.

If you fly a shield-tanked ship (I assume you're still flying a Caracal), you shouldn't let yourself get shot into armor. Just warp out and dock at a station to fill up your shields quickly again. Your only cost should be your ammunition. Some missions are harder, and you'll have some difficulties in the beginning when you're still learning, but if you have that much trouble in most missions you're doing something wrong.

You should learn about fitting your ship properly, making mistakes there can make a huge difference. Your skills also matter quite a bit in the beginning, even with only one or two weeks more worth of skills it'll get a lot easier. Make sure to have your main ship skill and your weapon skill at 4, basic shield skills and weapon skills at 3-4. Read [mission reports on EVE survival](http://www.evesurvival.caedwards.net/wikka.php-wakka=MissionReports.htm) to learn the triggers of the missions, that will help you to avoid aggroing too many enemies at once.

I'm keeping this a bit vague as there are whole guides written about these topics. I'd recommend to just read up on the basics of EVE combat and the missions should get far easier quickly. And don't mind losing money on the level 2 missions, train up for a Drake and try out the level 3 missions once you have the necessary skills.

Comment: Have to agree, either you are fit incorrectly, being a little impatient and aggroing too much, or, simply do not have the skill-set to run these missions without incurring high costs. The ammo and any other supplies you use should be standard stuff, rather than faction ammo.

Answer (score 1):

Minor disclaimer: I haven't played eve for a few months, so some of this advice may be out of date.

The most profit from missions in Eve generally comes from the salvage.  You should look to create a cheap salvage boat out of either a [Thrasher](http://eve.battleclinic.com/loadout/6356-Thrasher-Salvager.html) or a Cormorant (4x Tractor Beams, 4x Salvager 1s) and bookmark one of your wrecks (in each "room") after each mission, before returning to clean it up.  You can also pick up any modules and sell those.

Salvage such as Alloyed Titanium Bars or Armour Plates can sell for between 100k and 250k ISK each.

Modules such as the meta 4 target painter [Phased Weapon Navigation Array Generation Extron](http://www.eve-wiki.net/index.php?title=Target_Painters#Variants) can reach incredible prices in some areas (over 1m ISK per item in Dresi, I believe).

EDIT: As mentioned by @SteveV, this only applies to lower-level missions, such as the Level 2 missions the OP was interested in.  In higher-end missions, you'd replace the Thrasher / Cormorant with a Noctis (probably a dedicated member of your team, or someone hired to salvage for you).

Additionally, if you're running faction missions, you can turn some profit in buying loyalty benefits with the LP you gain and selling them - Although in my experience these don't make much unless you're in Faction Warfare, because missions give such small LP rewards.

Comment: This is true early on. Not so much at higher levels.

Comment: Thanks @SteveV. I've updated the answer to make this clear.

Comment: About faction rewards: implants seems to be around the best LP/ISK ratio you'll see. Named implants set are even better. (But way harder to farm.)